# echo/doubling of consonants in sanskrit

Tags: phonetics, sanskrit

I've notice that whenever people in india pronounce a sanskrit word where one syllable ends in a consonant and following syllable starts with a consonant, they tend to double up one of the consonant.

For example the word for horse in sanskrit is ashwa
But they pronounce it like ash-shwa
Here are some more examples

http://bhagavadgita.org.in/Chapters/18/4
The word puruṣa-vyāghra is pronounced as puruṣaV-vyāghra by the narrator.

Here https://www.aurobindo.ru/workings/matherials/rigveda/02/02-011.htm during recitation of
rigveda 02.011.20 (second voice clip, at around 05:33) mandínastritásya nyárbudam has been pronounced as mandínastritásyaN nyárbudam

Can anybody please elaborate on this ?

Comment: The word puruṣa-vyāghra is not _pronounced_, it is _sung_ just as the rest of the verse on that page. In singing words are often deformed to fit the melody and rhythm. But in that particular chant, what sounds for you like doubling is actually breaking the word into syllables this way: _pu.ru.ṢAV.yāgh.ra_.